# CentOS directory structure as tree?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Is there an equivalent to tree on CentOS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=35066). tree is not installed by default in CentOs, so you'll need to look for an RPM and install it manually

Comment: blah...not my server. Thanks though

Comment: The link is broken. The answer below works: sudo yum install tree -y

Answer (score 49):

If tree is not installed on your Centos system (I typically recommend server setups to use minimal install disk anyhow) you should type the following at your command line:

```
# yum install tree -y
```

If this doesn't install it's because you don't have the proper repository.  I would use the Dag Wieers repository:

http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/FAQ.php#B

After that you can do your install:

```
# yum install tree -y
```

Now you're ready to roll.  Always read the man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree

So quite simply the following will return a tree:

```
# tree
```

Alternatively you can output this to a text file.  There's a ton of options too..  Again, read your man page if you're looking for something other than default output.

```
# tree > recursive_directory_list.txt
```

(^^ in a text file for later review ^^)

Comment: what does -y mean?

Comment: -y means yes. Install thing and don’t prompt me to ask if I want to proceed with the installation.

Answer (score 19):

You can make your own primitive "tree" ( for fun :) )

```
#!/bin/bash
# only if you have bash 4 in your CentOS system
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*
do
    slash=${file//[^\/]}
    case "${#slash}" in
        0) echo "|-- ${file}";;
        1) echo "|   |--  ${file}";;
        2) echo "|   |   |--  ${file}";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks man, en lieu of Carlos's answer I'll add this to my .bash_profile

Comment: double blah they are running bash 3

Comment: And if you want to add color: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux

Answer (score 12):

Since `tree` is not installed by default in CentOS ...

```
[user@CentOS test]$ tree
-bash: tree: command not found
[user@CentOS test]$
```

You can also use the following `ls` command to produce almost similar output with `tree`

```
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

Example:

```
[user@CentOS test]$ ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
   .
   |-directory1
   |-directory2
   |-directory3
[user@CentOS directory]$
```

Comment: Nice! How would one edit this to also show filenames?

Answer (score 7):

You have tree in the base repo.

Show it (yum list package-name):

```
# yum list tree
Available Packages
tree.i386               1.5.0-4               base
```

Install it:

```
yum install tree
```

(verified on CentOS 5 and 6)

Answer (score 0):

I need to work on a remote computer that won't allow me to `yum` install. So I modified bash-o-logist's answer to get a more flexible one.

It takes an (optional) argument that is the maximum level of subdirectories you want to show. Add it to your `$PATH`, and enjoy a `tree` command that doesn't need installation.

I am not an expert in shell (I had to Google a ton of times just for this very short script). So if I did anything wrong, please let me know. Thank you so much!

```
#!/bin/bash
# only if you have bash 4 in your CentOS system

shopt -s globstar # enable double star

max_level=${1:-10}

for file in **
do
    # Get just the folder or filename
    IFS='/'
    read -ra ADDR <<< "$file"
    last_field=${ADDR[-1]}
    IFS=' '

    # Get the number of slashes
    slash=${file//[^\/]}
    
    # print folder or file with correct number of leadings
    if [ ${#slash} -lt $max_level ]
    then
        spaces="   "
        leading=""
        if [ "${#slash}" -gt 0 ]
        then
            leading=`eval $(echo printf '"|${spaces}%0.s"' {1..${#slash}})`
        fi
        echo "${leading}|-- $last_field"
    fi
done
```