# tree command is not working in UNIX OS?

Tags: unix

I am new to UNIX OS, tree command is not working on UNIX below is error, can you explain why it is so?

```
$tree
nologin: tree:  not found
```

Comment: Check this question to know how to install `tree` on your unix system ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732696/centos-directory-structure-as-tree!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are having issues running tree command on `UNIX`, it may be not install on your `UNIX OS`, you might have to find out how to install it on your specific distribution.